# How to catch mouse event over multiple divs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mouseevent

I have many components that are on top of each other, and I need to add a listener so when a mouse pointer is in bounds of these components every component will do something.

I tried with mouseover, mouseenter, mousemove, etc. but these events works only on the component that is on top, not on all of them.
ex html:

```
<div class="container">
    <app-child></app-child>
    <app-child></app-child>
    <app-child></app-child>
    <app-child></app-child>
</div>
```

ex css:

```
.container > * {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

ex app-child.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
ChildComponent {
    
    // Here some function that needs to run if mouse pointer is in bound of this element

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you want the children to do something**

parent.component.html

```
<div class="container" (mouseenter)="doSomethingFunction()" (mouseleave)="stopDoSomething()>
    <app-child [doSomething]="doSomething"></app-child>
    <app-child [doSomething]="doSomething"></app-child>
    <app-child [doSomething]="doSomething"></app-child>
    <app-child [doSomething]="doSomething"></app-child>
</div>
```

parent.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
ParentComponent {

   
    doSomething = false;
    doSomethingFunction(e) {
        doSomething = true;
    }

    stopDoSomething(e) {
        doSomething = false;      
    }

}
```

child.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
ChildComponent {
    @Input() doSomething: boolean

    
    ngOnInit() {
         if(doSomething) {
             doSomethingElse();
         } else {
             stopDoingThings();
         }
    }

}
```

**if you have to do something to the children**

parent.component.html

```
<div class="container" (mouseenter)="doSomething($event)">
    <app-child></app-child>
    <app-child></app-child>
    <app-child></app-child>
    <app-child></app-child>
</div>
```

parent.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
ParentComponent {

    
    doSomething(e) {
        for(const child in Array.from(e.target.children) {
            doSomethingElse(child);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but is there a way to check if the mouse pointer is in bounds of this child? Cause in your answer this will always get every single child, and the issue is that these children don't always have the same position :)

Comment: you can create an array of the `doSomething` booleand and bind each element of the array to a component. The only way to be sure if the pointer is in bound of a specific child is to set a different `mouseenter` callback for each child.

Comment: Yeah, but this mouseenter callback will be triggered only on the first child on top, no?

Comment: no, have you checked if you maybe have some issue with the bounds of the elements inside the browser?